# laravel - file not uploading to uploads folder

Tags: php, file, laravel, upload

This is a follow-up question to the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827365/laravel-uploading-files/36828662#36828662) question I asked. I added the code as instructed, but now all I get when my form hits the upload field I just get redirected bacl to the form.

Here is my view:

```
@extends('app');

@section('content');
    <h1>Add a new item</h1>
    <hr />
    <content>
        <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'item.store', 'files' => true]) !!}
        {!! Form::label('name', "Name") !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

       {!! Form::label('filename', "File Name") !!}
        {!! Form::file('filename', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

        {!! Form::label('description', 'Description') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Add Item', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}

    </content>
</div>

@stop
```

Here is my controller

```
      public function store(Requests\CreateItem $request)
    {


        Item::create($request->all());

//        if (Input::hasFile('filename')) {
//            $file = $request->file('filename');
//            $file->move(public_path().'/uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());
//
//            echo "File Uploaded";
//
//        }
        dd(Input::all());




    }
```

and here's my routes

```
    <?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
Route::resource('item', 'ItemController');

Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::post('/item/create', ['as' => 'item.store', 'uses' => 'ItemController@store']);

Route::get('/item', 'ItemController@store');

//Route
```

Any suggestions?
Edit: here is my Requests\CreateItem.php file

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CreateItem extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true; // for now
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'filename', 'required|min:7',

        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's got to be something in `Requests\CreateItem` which is failing.  Can you show us some relevant code in there?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think that You should remove this line:

`Route::post('/item/create', ['as' => 'item.store', 'uses' => 'ItemController@store']);`

If You want to change somethink in route (name or controller method) You should place it before this line:

`Route::resource('item', 'ItemController');`

Your routes order is wrong thats why You've got back to the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found my answer. `'filename', 'required|min:7',` should be `filename => 'required|min:7'`